# Merge queries in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to merge these 2 queries into one query

```
SELECT COUNT(IMA.FKRiskID) AS RiskCountWithoutPlan 
 FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38
  AND IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (   
       select 1 
         from RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP                
        where IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID
     )   
SELECT COUNT(IMA.FKRiskID) AS RiskCountWithPlan
 FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA 
WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38 
  AND  IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%'
  AND EXISTS (  
                  select 1 
                    from RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP                 
                   where IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID
             )
```

Comment: You are not very specific about what you want the result to be. I think you could remove the exists and not exists, but I don't think this is the result you want.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? You want to write one query to get two different counts with different conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It worked for me using dummy data (I'll post the query as a comment).  This will give you two columns: first is RiskCountWithoutPlan second is RiskCountWithPlan

```
SELECT 
    SUM([rcwop]) [RiskCountWithoutPlan],
    SUM([rcwp]) [RiskCountWithPlan]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwop],
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwp]
    FROM 
        Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
        LEFT JOIN RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP ON IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID              
    WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38
  AND IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' 
) tbl
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Stu

---

```
DECLARE @Rpt_ImpactAssessment TABLE (
    FKRiskID INT, 
    FKItemID INT,
    FKPlanID INT,
    ImpactCurPIDLevel NVARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @RM_LinkActionToPlan TABLE (
    FKRiskID INT, 
    FKItemID INT,
    PlanID  INT,
    ImpactCurPIDLevel NVARCHAR(20)
)


INSERT INTO @Rpt_ImpactAssessment VALUES (1, 38, 2, 'High')
INSERT INTO @RM_LinkActionToPlan VALUES (1, 38, 2, 'High')

INSERT INTO @Rpt_ImpactAssessment VALUES (1, 38, 3, 'High')
INSERT INTO @RM_LinkActionToPlan VALUES (1, 38, 3, 'High')


SELECT 
    SUM([rcwop]) [RiskCountWithoutPlan],
    SUM([rcwp]) [RiskCountWithPlan]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwop],
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwp]
    FROM 
        @Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
        LEFT JOIN @RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP ON IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID              
    WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38
  AND IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' 
) tbl
```

Comment: Ah, can't add it as a comment. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You are right only thing is we have to add Distinct for filtering             SELECT 
  DISTINCT IMA.FKRiskID,
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwop],
        CASE WHEN LAP.PlanID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [rcwp]

Comment: Avoid DISTINCT.  It's considered bad practice.  Have a read of this http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/09/30/from_clauses.html for a bit more info.